# from X import Y works in the terminal, but not in a script executed from the terminal

Tags: python, import, terminal, nltk

I'm running Python 2.7.3 and Mac OS 10.8.5. I downloaded all the packages and data from nltk.org and have been able to use them quite successfully in the terminal one line at a time. I want to write my own script with them, and this seems to be a problem.

If I open the terminal and type:

```
  cd nltk_data
  python
  from nltk.book import *
```

it executes perfectly. If I open the terminal and type:

```
python mycode1.py
```

where "mycode1.py" looks like this:

```
  import os
  os.chdir('MyDirectory/nltk_data')
  from nltk.book import *
```

it fails with the error:

```
ImportError: No module named book
```

I thought maybe it was the working directory causing problems, even though adding os.getcwd() to the above code shows I'm in the right working directory. If I open up a fresh terminal and try:

```
    cd nltk_data
    python mycode2.py
```

Where mycode2.py looks like:

```
from nltk.book import *
```

It fails with the same error. I can run scripts from the terminal though.

```
python four.py
```

where four.py looks like:

```
print 2+2
```

Works fine. The * doesn't seem to be the problem either, as I tried the above with a specific item as well, with the same results. It seems that the from X import Y function within a script run from the terminal is the problem, but from X import Y in the terminal works. I tried several variants, like:

```
    import nltk
    import nltk.book
```

And still get that "book" is a module that doesn't exist if I ask for it from a script (but again it works fine if I ask for it from the terminal).

I tried searching for a similar error and there was something about appending sys.path but I understand how/why I would do this? I also am somewhat confused since "book" is not the name of any file or folder in the nltk_data directory I downloaded. I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Did you install the packages via pip? or simply downloaded the source to your dekstop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've called something else "nltk.py". Remove/rename that file and any associated compiled bytecode files.

Comment: This was exactly what happened. Renamed the file, everything works perfect! Thanks!!